# Подсчет ширины контрола, по длине строки

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Собственно есть старый и мохнатый уже легаси код, контролы реализованы на WinForms, а времени и денег на переписывание на WPF нету. Его используем как можем, каждый раз когда внедряем какой нибудь контрол в WPF, вылезают баги.

Сейчас баг немного специфичный. Есть контрол, внутри контрола `Label`, ширина которого рассчитывается так :

```
return (int) LabelControl.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(TextLabel, TextLabel.Font).Width + 40;
```

Если смотреть на WinForms тестовом приложении, все отлично. Если вбить контрол внутрь WPF, он берет текст и если там есть пробелы, то переносит текст, врапит.

Есть вариант хардкода, подменять строку на модифицированную, и заменить пробелы на любой другой символ, но это еще пока предположение, есть какие либо более уместные и гибкие пути?

Comment: Эээ, а что означает «вбить контрол внутрь WPF»?

Comment: @VladD использовать внутри WPF приложения

Comment: WinForms-контрол? o_O

Comment: @VladD WinForms UserControl

Comment: А WinForms-UserControl можно использовать в WPF? Не знал.

Comment: @VladD, можно встраивать что угодно из WinForms через [`WinFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875(v=vs.110).aspx). Работает правда иногда специфически.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост. Переписал просто расчет, добавил пикселей 10. Почему такое поведение, и почему именно надо добавить 10 пикселей не могу предположить, скорее всего, в других приложениях, кстати винформовских, на этот контрол вешается Margin.